# JPA 2.0 / EclipseLink and sqlite 3.7.2 - Can't create the tables

Tags: java, sqlite, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I'd like to use JPA 2.0 with EclipseLink (2.4.0) and sqlite 3.7.2 in a simple Java Swing application.

The first thing I have encountered is, that EclipseLink doesn't support sqlite. Here is the output:

> [EL Info]: 2012-09-18 18:05:42.246--ServerSession(31125695)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652
>
> [EL Info]: connection: 2012-09-18 18:05:42.352--Not able to detect platform for vendor name [SQLite3]. Defaulting to [org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DatabasePlatform]. The database dialect used may not match with the database you are using. Please explicitly provide a platform using property eclipselink.platform.class.name.

However, it seems to me, that the configuration works almost fine.

But when I have a model with related Entities (i.e. @ManyToOne) the tables can't be created automatically.

> [EL Warning]: 2012-09-18 18:05:42.629--ServerSession(31125695)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "CONSTRAINT": syntax error)
>   Error Code: 0
>
> Call: ALTER TABLE blub ADD CONSTRAINT FK_blub_customer_id FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer (customer_id)
>
> Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER TABLE blub ADD CONSTRAINT FK_blub_customer_id FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer (customer_id)")

As you can see, the additional creation of foreign key constraints isn't supported by sqlite.

Do you have any idea how to fix the problem?

Best regards

Comment: FWIW, SQLite supports foreign keys (with the right, _recommended_ pragma) but doesn't support adding them with `ALTER TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your own DatabasePlatform subclass and add the method,

```
public boolean supportsForeignKeyConstraints() {
        return false;
}
```

Then use this platform using the "eclipselink.target-database" property.

Please also log a bug to have SQLite support added, and attach your platform if you are successful creating one.

**UPDATE 18/08/2015**
Not sure if this option is new, you can now set `foreign_keys` to `false` in the JDBC connection configuration/properties. In such way you will avoid these warning messages and it will create the foreign keys as needed.
One way to set it is using:

```
SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
config.enforceForeignKeys(false);
Properties dbProps = config.toProperties();
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Before sending a working solution (as attachment to a bugreport) I'd like to make some tests.

Comment: This bug doesn't seem to be fixed in eclipselink 2.5.1

Comment: Still not fixed in eclipselink 2.6.2